# CSS3 - Transparent Border appears on Box Shadow for multiple line title in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, box-shadow

Transparent Border appears on title background with box shadow between box shadow and background in Internet Explorer (9,10, Edge).

[Please check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ot5.jpg)

This is the Style i have added:

```
background: rgb(130, 210, 250); 
box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px #82d2fa, -10px 0px 0px #82d2fa;
```

In some Stack Overflow Answers they have mentioned to put `box-decoration-break: clone;` but its does not support Internet Explorer. Is there any workaround?

Please Refer to Below Link: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/WmRT3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.title {
  font: 20px/1.25 Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
.title .highlight {
  display: inline;
  background: #ee4035;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
.title.step-1 .highlight {
  box-shadow: -10px 0 0 #ee4035,-10px 0 0 #ee4035;  
}
```